# Is there a way to rank the Extracted Named Entities based on their importance/occurence in a document?

Tags: nlp, named-entity-recognition

Looking for a way to rank the tens and hundreds of named entities present in any document in order of their importance/relevance in the context.

Any thoughts ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

An easy way would be to use [TF-IDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf) (term frequency–inverse document frequency). It can help you find how much terms stand out in a document (by comparing with your entire corpus) and use it to rank your entities.

[TfidfVectorizer from scikit-learn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html)

Just note that the TfidfVectorizer is on a word level. So some processing will be needed if your entities can consist of more than one word.

Alternatively you could use a model that allows you to produce a heatmap of the words. Then you can use that heatmap to look up your NEs in that heatmap. This paper, [A Structured Self-Attentive Sentence Embedding](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1703.03130.pdf), could give you some ideas.

Comment: Thanks for your response, Simon! However, I was wondering if there is a better approach since tf-idf will not take into consideration the context of the document.

Comment: You are correct. I think you can achieve what you are looking for by using a self-attention model. I will link something in my answer.